# GPU clock speed in Android

Tags: android, gpu

I am trying to find the GPU clock speed in Android.
So far no luck. Is that possible at all? I cannot find any instruction in order to get the hardware clock speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android does not provide APIs for low level interaction with the GPU.  Depending on the meaning of "Android" it is not entirely clear that there has to even be a GPU - the emulator would be a common example of something that does not, and basic ports to various development boards could be another.

It is possible, though sadly unlikely, that a given device vendor might choose to publicize some low-level programming information.  Unfortunately, details of how to work with the GPU tend to be things that they hold quite closely and refuse to disclose - they argue it would give an advantage to their competitors - perhaps, but what it clearly does is prevent open source implementations of accelerated graphics drivers.

Even beyond the availability of information, there is the issue of access permission.  The graphics hardware in Android is owned by system components such as surfaceflinger, and on secured devices not really made available for direct interaction by 3rd party application code.

Ultimately though, even if you could find a number it would not mean much.  Clock speed of the internal engine does not tell you the number of clock cycles needed to complete an operation, the number of parallel operations which can be in process, what delays are encountered in moving data to/from memory and what caches are available, the efficiency of algorithms, etc.  You might be better off benchmarking some performance test.